# Block the pop out of default keyboard on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

How to disable or block the default keyboard when we focusing on the input textfield or textarea etc.?

I have already tried:

1. blur(), readonly. For the initial input tag. It is ok with that but the bug is users cannot select the text afterward.
2. Using div-contenteditable="true" to replace input html. However, still pop up default keyboard.

I already have my virtual keyboard, wanna find a way to disable the default one so not to cover my virtual on mobile devices.

Comment: depends on the input type(s) you are using and the device(s)

Comment: FWIW, it may be better in terms of usability to let users enter text using their own input application, rather than forcing one upon them.